# Count height of all divs

Tags: jquery

I need to count total height of all divs, but I get a height of just one...

```
var myHeight = function() {
    var dHeight = 0;
    $(".myItem").each(function() {
        dHeight += $(this).height();
    });
    return dHeight;
}
```

Does this look right?

Comment: With jQuery, always suspect the selectors first. Run `alert($('.myItem').length)` - how many? The code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you meant `return dHeight`, not `return myHeight` (the latter is the function, not the incremented variable).

[EDIT - as per the OP's comment below, this was apparently a typo and is not the reason for the problem]

Comment: oops, type. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your code is right. Look at my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/SESkv/). Thus, wrapping it in a function and returning `dHeight` should be ok to achieve what you want to do.

**UPDATE** Ok, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/SESkv/1/) your function in action working fine. Your code is short, well-written, very readable and does what it should (try resizing  the `div`'s heights by adding `<br />`'s).